# UIView ignoring setHidden when in animation block

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, hidden, uistackview

I have this code on an `UIView` subclass:

```
override var hidden: Bool {
    willSet {
        DDLogDebug("Will set hidden=\(String(newValue)) on \(item?.name))")
    }
    didSet {
        DDLogDebug("Did set hidden=\(String(hidden)) on \(item?.name))")
    }
}
```

For some reason, I set `false` but it remains `true` as seen in these logs:

```
> Will set hidden=false on Optional("74D8E4CE-5E14-4914-8483-E9F66D2A79B7"))

> Did set hidden=true on Optional("74D8E4CE-5E14-4914-8483-E9F66D2A79B7"))
```

The only peculiarity of this issue is that it only happens when running inside a `UIView.animateWithDuration(...)` block. If I remove the animation the property is set correctly.

Any thoughts on what may be going on? This is driving me crazy, heh

Edit:

Little bit more info, this UIView I want to hide is an `arrangedSubview` of a `UIStackView`. It works correctly for the first few tries but suddenly stops working without any noticeable pattern.

Comment: I think you're hitting a stack view bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240635/hidden-property-cannot-be-changed-within-an-animation-block

Comment: thanks @jrturton for linking that, wondering how that didn't appear in my search results heh, it's definitely a bug in UIStackView and I've fixed it by avoiding setting hidden to the same value twice. Thanks again you made my day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in UIStackView.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240635/hidden-property-cannot-be-changed-within-an-animation-block) is another question describing the exact same issue I'm having. [This](http://www.openradar.me/22819594) is an open radar for this specific issue.

The solution I found was to avoid setting `hidden` to the same value twice.

```
if (subview.hidden) {
    subview.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have been tracking down an issue similar to this when rotating the device. After more hours and more work arounds than I care to admit to, I found this, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it works for me

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    arrangedSubview.hidden = isHidden;
}];
```